# minecraft player.sendMessage command plugin not working

Tags: java

I'm new to coding and I am making a Minecraft command plugin for my mate, the plugin sends a message to the player when they use the command. I can't seem to get all of them working, only the first command will work on the server, I've tried everything I know like if-else, etc can someone help, please?

```
package com.legroom.applyplugin.Commands;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

public class commands implements CommandExecutor {

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

        Player player = (Player) sender;
        if (sender == null) {
        }

        if
        (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("famous")) {
            player.sendMessage("§7§m----------------------------");
            player.sendMessage("§3» §3Requirements:");
            player.sendMessage("§3» §f500+ Subscribers");
            player.sendMessage("§3» §f1+ vid on the server");
            player.sendMessage("§3» §fReasonable views/likes");
            player.sendMessage("");
            player.sendMessage("§3» To apply, use:");
            player.sendMessage("§3    » §fMedia.nivina.cc");
            player.sendMessage("");
            player.sendMessage("§m----------------------------");

            if
            (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("appeal")) {
                player.sendMessage("§7§m----------------------------");
                player.sendMessage("");
                player.sendMessage("§3» To appeal, use:");
                player.sendMessage("§3     »§fDiscord.nivina.cc");
                player.sendMessage("");
                player.sendMessage("§7§m----------------------------");

                if
                (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("apply")) {
                    player.sendMessage("§7§m----------------------------");
                    player.sendMessage("");
                    player.sendMessage("§3» To apply, use:");
                    player.sendMessage("§3    » §fStaff.nivina.cc");
                    player.sendMessage("§3    » §fMedia.nivina.cc");
                    player.sendMessage("");
                    player.sendMessage("§7§m----------------------------");


                    if
                    (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("youtube")) {
                        player.sendMessage("§7§m----------------------------");
                        player.sendMessage("§3» §3Requirements:");
                        player.sendMessage("§3 » §f200+ Subscribers");
                        player.sendMessage("   » §f1+ vid on the server");
                        player.sendMessage("§3 » §fReasonable views/likes");
                        player.sendMessage("");
                        player.sendMessage("§3» To apply, use:");
                        player.sendMessage("§3» §fMedia.nivina.cc");
                        player.sendMessage("");
                        player.sendMessage("§m----------------------------");
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are nesting your if-statements:

```
if (condition) {
   if (someOtherConditionThatConflictsWithFirstCondition) {
     // Never reached
   }
}
```

The second if-statement, because it is contained *within* the curly braces of the first, is only reached if the first condition evaluates to true. But your conditions are equals-operations on the same String, so if the first condition evaluates to `true`, the second cannot evaluate to `true`.

What you need to do instead is place them after one another:

```
if (condition) {
}
if (someOtherCondition) {
}
if (thirdCondition) {
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
if (condition) {
}
else if (someOtherCondition) {
}
else if (thirdCondition) {
}
```